# Programmatically replace cell of TableLayout (with complex layout)

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

In my app I have a table with somewhat complex layout: it is a 3x3 table, with the top and left being static headers, and the other four cells each containing a table again with my information.

This internal table has two options, and I programmatically select which of the two to use, and add them to the table. So far so good.

Now when updating the information in the table, a second table is added to the cell, instead of the original one being replaced. So after a few updates, my main table becomes huge, and the cells in it really high with a number of internal tables. Of course that's not the idea.

```
private int setTable(int minAPI, int maxAPI, TableLayout tableId) {

    // Get the levels that belong to the API.
    String minLevel = getLevel(minAPI);
    String maxLevel = getLevel(maxAPI);

    // Get an inflater to inflate the table layouts.
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Get the layout of the API/Level table. 
    // Which one to use for the levels depends on whether the levels are 
    // the same or not.
    TextView textLevelFrom = null;
    TextView textLevelTo = null;
    TableLayout tableLayout = null;

    if (minLevel.equals(maxLevel)) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Setting up api_table1.");
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.api_table1, tableId);
        textLevelFrom = (TextView) tableLayout.findViewById(R.id.textLevel);
        textLevelFrom.setText(minLevel);        
        textLevelFrom.setTextColor(getColour(minAPI));  
    }

    else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Setting up api_table2.");
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.api_table2, tableId);
        textLevelFrom = (TextView) tableLayout.findViewById(R.id.textLevelFrom);
        textLevelFrom.setText(minLevel);        
        textLevelFrom.setTextColor(getColour(minAPI));  
        textLevelTo = (TextView) tableLayout.findViewById(R.id.textLevelTo);
        textLevelTo.setText(maxLevel);
        textLevelTo.setTextColor(getColour(maxAPI));
    }

    Log.v(TAG, "Populating the table.");

    TextView textAPIFrom = (TextView) tableLayout.findViewById(R.id.textAPIFrom);
    textAPIFrom.setText(""+minAPI);     
    textAPIFrom.setTextColor(getColour(minAPI));

    TextView textAPITo = (TextView) tableLayout.findViewById(R.id.textAPITo);
    textAPITo.setText(""+maxAPI);
    textAPITo.setTextColor(getColour(maxAPI));

    textLevelFrom.setText(minLevel);        
    textLevelFrom.setTextColor(getColour(minAPI));

    return tableLayout.getId();
}
```

The `TableLayout TableId` is previously found by a call like

```
tableCurrentGeneral = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.CurrentGeneral);
```

one for each of the four cells. The main table is defined in main.xml; the cells of these table are an empty TableLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.squirrel.hkairpollution.MySupportMapFragment"
    />
<!-- class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" -->

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableAPI" 
        android:background="@color/translucent_white"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/map">

        <!-- First row: headers. -->
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="@string/general" 
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:paddingRight="8dip" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/roadside" 
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </TableRow>

        <!-- Second row: current API -->                
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/current" 
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <!-- Current API, general stations -->
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/CurrentGeneral"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:paddingRight="8dip" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/CurrentRoadside"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Third row: forecast API -->
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/forecast" 
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <!-- Forecast API, general stations -->
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/ForecastGeneral"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:paddingRight="8dip" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/ForecastRoadside"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/map" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/map"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/refresh"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/map" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/map"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The line

```
tableLayout = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.api_table1, tableId);
```

correctly links the api_table1 resp. api_table2 layouts to the desired cells, but all the time this layout is added, it's not being replaced.

I unsuccessfully tried handing back the id of the just added view, to remove it later:

```
tableAPI.removeView(findViewById(tableCurrentRoadsideId));
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Interesting to see my question being edited (that word "unsuccessfully" isn't mine), and I think wrongly. I do get back an id (easy check: it's an int that's initialised as =0 and later it's !=0), and have all reason to believe it's the correct id. What else could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it through a slightly different route.

I wrongly believed that when you attach a view to a cell again, it is a second view that is attached to it. Instead, my table was appending more rows to itself.

And also so much for no documentation on the actual workings of `TableLayout.removeView()`

The solution: at the start of `setTable` a line that removes all the views from that table. That clears up this table, after which I can re-attach my layout, and all is as it should be.

```
private void setTable(int minAPI, int maxAPI, TableLayout tableId) {
    tableId.removeAllViews();
    ...
```